# Error CS1061 object does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extention method 'text'

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a digital clock in Unity. The text in this line of code

```
textClock.text = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
```

gives me error CS1061: Type 'object does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' of type 'object' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I have tried

`private Text text;` and `public Text text;`

because I thought I needed to declare it, but that isn't the case. What am I missing?

I have included all of the code below in case it's needed. Thank you for taking the time to read and answer my question.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System; 

public class ClockDigital : MonoBehaviour {
private object textClock;


public class Clock : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text textClock;


    private void Start()
    {
        textClock = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

}

private void Update()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    string hour = LeadingZero(time.Hour);
    string minute = LeadingZero(time.Minute);
    string second = LeadingZero(time.Second);


    textClock.text = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}

string LeadingZero (int n)
{
    return n.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
}

}
```

Comment: You have two different `textClock` objects - one inside `Clock` (which is of type `Text`) and one inside the surrounding class `ClockDigital` (which is of type `object`)

Comment: The error is not wrong. `private object textClock;` System.Object does not have a Text property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error CS1061: Type 'object does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' of type 'object' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

The first clue here is `Type 'object'`. That means that you are referencing an Object, which the base Object class does not have a `.text` property.

Change your `private object textClock;` declaration to `private Text textClock;`. You have both in your code, although your nested class declarations smells of bad copypasta. Just make sure each declaration is `private Text`.